# COULD NOT LOAD TYPE 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib'

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm creating an ASP.NET API Core application, to handle API services, which communicate to an Oracle Database.

At runtime, when the process tries to connect to the DB with a new Oracle Connection throught a DbContext ( Entity Framework) an unhandled error appears and forces the app to stop.

```
myDbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
```

This line causes the following error

> System.TypeLoadException : 'Could not load type
> 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly
> 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx'.'

I had an old but similar project which used the same code and worked properly.
The library used is the same for Oracle Connector : **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework**

What I tried :

- Unistall - Reinstall Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework,
- same for other Oracle connector ( Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core )
- Install System.Security.Principal
- Changing the target framework from 3.1 to 5

I went first to this page ['System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib' error when trying to parse template with Razor Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377435/system-security-principal-windowsimpersonationcontext-from-assembly-mscorlib) but did not find anything that could help me resolve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579818/impersonating-user-in-asp-net-core/68579915#68579915

Comment: same worked, i didnt upgraded Framework 3.1 to 5, not installed System.Security.Principal also.. just installed Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core alone, earlier i had Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess alone

Comment: Any update on the solution?

Answer (score 8):

For dot net 6, I was getting the same exception. Only kept the package: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core and removed all others related to oracle and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess'. I had both 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess' and 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core' installed. This issue is most likely caused because 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess' is for .NET Framework and not .NET Core/.NET 6.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with .NET Core/.NET2, here is what I did: I removed

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.client

and installed

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core

from NuGet packages but i had to select version below < 3.x that has no dependencies

Comment: Are you reporting a solution that worked for you or asking for help? This is currently unclear. Please clarify (only the first one would be allowed)

Comment: Please [edit] according to [answer] to make more obvious that you are trying to answer isntead of describing your own problem.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was doing wrong! I changed the NuGet project and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The .NET Core version has the same name as the .NET Framework version `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` but with a lower version number. As a result, Visual Studio takes the higher version from the GAC rather than the NuGet package. -> Delete the GAC version.