# Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext on .Net 6 and EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

We are currently migrating our projects which are developed on .NET472 to .NET6.0. We had used EF6 for Oracle DB connection and it has now been done via Oracle.Manageddataaccess. Now after we changed the underlying projects, we are getting an error as mentioned later. We found there were two feasible solutions on net but we had some issues:

1. **Change from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core:**

   - This needs application to be moved EFCore, but we can't do this since we can't move all our code from EF6 to EFCore now.
2. **Add reference to Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility:**

   - I have added that but still we are getting same error.

The error is as follows:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

Here are the references which I have already tried:

1. [Type Load Exception for WindowsImpersonationContext (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593542/could-not-load-type-system-security-principal-windowsimpersonationcontext-from)
2. [You must add reference to mscorlib (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468552/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-mscorlib-version-4-0-0)

Comment: What was the point of migrating .Net 6 if not to take advantage of EF Core? It is not a big deal and there are a lot of benefits. This is my goto article to explain how, why and when:  [Port from EF6 to EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/#perform-the-upgrade-steps)

Comment: Changing to EF Core is taking lot of changes, we have a framework which is being utilized by multiple applications, we have already tried with the steps in the link you have mentioned but it is not an apple to apple migration. and we faced issues on multiple places starting from Entities so decided not to EFCore at the current situation.